# Compare date in Oracle when some value is null?

Tags: oracle

I want to get records that have an expired_date less than "31/12/2015", but some value of expired_date field is null in the database. This is my SQL:

```
"AND TO_DATE(EXPIRED_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY') < TO_DATE('31/12/2015','DD/MM/YYYY')"
```

so I have got an error

```
"day of the month must between 1 and the last day of the month"
```

How can I get just records that have an expired_date < '31/12/2015'?

EDIT: The problem is not the null value, but my format in my DB. I store "22-APR-15" and mistake is trying to assign it to 'DD/MM/YYYY' by to_date function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your column `EXPIRED_DATE` is of date type then, you don't need to convert it to date again using `TO_DATE`.

I think you need the following:

```
AND EXPIRED_DATE < TO_DATE('31/12/2015','DD/MM/YYYY')
```

This will return false for any `EXPIRED_DATE` which is null and that record will not be included in the result.

If you want Null `EXPIRED_DATE` to be included in the result then you can use OR as following:

```
AND (EXPIRED_DATE IS NULL OR EXPIRED_DATE < TO_DATE('31/12/2015','DD/MM/YYYY'))
```

Comment: FYI: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions

Comment: @DaleK Removing the **Cheers!!** do not make any improvement in the answer. Even the link you provided do not suggest to remove such word. But anyway thanks for taking a look at the answer and helping the community but sorry, I can not remove Cheers word as I think it is the sign of good communication and makes the person feel good.

Comment: *"Anything that is not relevant to the question/post is noise and should be removed"*. The point of the site is to be a good source of information, not to feel good. In a years time when someone comes across this question the "cheers" will be meaningless.

Comment: @DaleK Yeah, OK. respected. Thanks.

Comment: your instruction help me solve my problem, thank you very much @Tejash

Answer (score 0):

Your code `...E(EXPIRED_DATE,'DD/MM/YYY')...` has 3 `YYY` for date instead of 4 `YYYY`. Tried below and it works

```
with da(date_a) as (
    select '03/04/2015' from dual
    union all select '03/04/2015' from dual
    union all select '03/04/2017' from dual
    union all select '03/04/2015' from dual
    union all select '03/04/2016' from dual
    union all select NULL from dual
)
SELECT * FROM da WHERE   TO_DATE(date_a,'DD/MM/YYYY') < TO_DATE('31/12/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Even when your date column is in date format it will still work

```
with da(date_a) as (
    select '03/04/2015' from dual
    union all select '03/04/2015' from dual
    union all select '03/04/2017' from dual
    union all select '03/04/2015' from dual
    union all select '03/04/2016' from dual
    union all select NULL from dual
)
SELECT to_date(date_a, 'DD/MM/YYYY')  date_a  FROM da WHERE   TO_DATE(date_a,'DD/MM/YYYY') < TO_DATE('31/12/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=385c6cc85bf7c726a722228de9599556)

Comment: thanks, @Omari Victor Omosa, but the problem is my function to_date ( actually a write YYYY in my SQL). My mistake is value in my DB is not in 'DD/MM/YYYY' format, so I got an error when used to_date(EXPIRED_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY')

Comment: got you this could do also `to_date(EXPIRED_DATE, 'the_format_that_is_in_your_db')`